# What is a constant phase plane?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

I have a electromagnetic wave propagating in an arbitrary direction in the space.
[image]

I do understand that the electric magnetic fields are constant in a plane normal to the direction of propagation.

My professor says that this plane where the electric and magnetic fields are constant also has constant phase.

I want to understand what does this mean? What does it imply to have constant phase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider equation of the plane passing through an arbitrary point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ and perpendicular to a given direction delineated by the propagation vector $\mathbf{k}$. See the figure

[image]

The vector $\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_0$ will sweep out the desired plane provided that
$$(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_0)\cdot \mathbf{k}=0$$

$$\mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{r}=\text{constant }$$
The equation of the wave (electric or magnetic)
$$\psi(\mathbf{r})=A\sin(\mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{r})$$
is a function defined on a family of plane all perpendicular to $\mathbf{k}$. Over each of these $\mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{r}=\text{constant}$, and so $\psi(\mathbf{r})$ varies sinusoidally.

That's what we meant by constant phase plane.

---